# Magento 2.2.2 Add Product Attributes Under Custom Tab on Product Page

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2

I have created a **custom tab** on **product page** (**just like details, more information, reviews**). I want to show product **attributes** like **quantity**, **color**, **price** etc. under this custom tab.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @jigsparmar: i am not able to display product color, quantity and sku.

Comment: Please log product all the data and check that product return all the data or not first

Comment: @jigsparmar: i didn't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info("options", array('options data', $product->getData()));

and check system.log file

Comment: @jigsparmar: what should i check in system.log file to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does it print the value of color and  quantity???

Answer (score 1):

we write one blog for create tab in Product view Page in Frontend
in https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-tab-in-magento-2-product-page/
page you found the code to create custom tab

Answer (score 1):

> app\code\Ravindra\Extension\view\frontend\templates\custom_tab.phtml

```
<?php // Get current product
$product = $block->getProduct();
?>

<h1 style="color: #ff5501">
 <?php echo $product->getData('quantity'); ?>
 <?php echo $product->getData('color'); ?>
 <?php echo $product->getData('price'); ?>
</h1>
```

Comment: i have implemented this, only price is displaying under custom but. Color and quantity are not displaying.